# Disagreement between isfile and listdir in Python

Tags: python, directory

```
filter(os.path.isfile,os.listdir('DIRECTORY'))
```

Returns different results than:

```
os.listdir('DIRECTORY')
```

In a directory of CSV files, the listdir command returns a set of files (as expected), but the filter returns nothing (unexpected)

Comment: Want to see the list of directory, and also how the filter was implemented.

Comment: Did you prepend the directory to the file? `listdir("\path\to\dir\")` will return something like `["file1.txt", "file2.dat",...]` you then need to call `isfile("\path\to\dir\file1.txt")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.listdir(path) #will return all content of that folder


filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(path)) # will return only list of files
filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(path))  # will return only list of directories
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir()` returns a list of filenames that do *not* include the path.  That means `os.listdir("/home/zondo")` might give `["dir1", "file1", "file2"]`.  Now let's say we're in `dir1` at the execution of this command.  We first see if `dir1` exists.  It doesn't so `filter()` moves to the next.  Why doesn't it exist?  Because we didn't provide an absolute path; we provided a relative path.  Since we're in `dir1`, `os.path.isfile()` is seeing if `/home/zondo/dir1/dir1` is a file.  Of course it isn't; it doesn't exist.  You need to provide the path with it.  You could use a `lambda` function:

```
filter(lambda x: os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, x)), os.listdir("DIRECTORY"))
```

It would probably be better in this case to use a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in os.listdir("DIRECTORY") if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, x))]
```